# In IRKernel::installspec(): jupyter kernelspec --version exits with code one

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

Trying to install the IRKernel for jupyter notebook, I am facing the following issue:

```
IRkernel::installspec()
# Results in
# Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
# jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 1.
```

This is related to the fact that on Windows, a dash is needed. Indeed, this doesn't work:

```
> jupyter kernelspec --version
Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelspec': [Errno 'jupyter-kernelspec' not found] 2
```

While this works:

```
> jupyter-kernelspec --version
5.2.2
```

Is there any way around this?

My OS is

```
> ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.431]
```

And my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16         digest_0.6.15        crayon_1.3.4         IRdisplay_0.5.0      repr_0.15.0         
 [6] jsonlite_1.5         magrittr_1.5         evaluate_0.10.1      stringi_1.1.7        uuid_0.1-2          
[11] rstudioapi_0.7       IRkernel_0.8.12.9000 tools_3.5.0          stringr_1.3.1        yaml_2.1.19         
[16] compiler_3.5.0       base64enc_0.1-3      pbdZMQ_0.3-3         htmltools_0.3.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the `Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelspec'` issue here:
[Jupyter commands work only with a dash (e.g. jupyter-kernelspec instead of jupyter kernelspec)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50484397/2699660)

To install the R Kernel, the workaround I used was to tweak the [installspec function's code](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/blob/e1396db82365a548aa99ee8014f56fad2720bf00/R/installspec.r) and execute this tweaked version locally.

The modification was to replace:

```
17: exit_code <- system2('jupyter', c('kernelspec', '--version'), FALSE, FALSE)
42: args <- c('kernelspec', 'install', '--replace', '--name', name, user_flag, prefix_flag, file.path(tmp_name, 'kernelspec'))
43: exit_code <- system2('jupyter', args)
```

By:

```
17: exit_code <- system2('jupyter-kernelspec', '--version', FALSE, FALSE)
42: args <- c('install', '--replace', '--name', name, user_flag, prefix_flag, file.path(tmp_name, 'kernelspec'))
43: exit_code <- system2('jupyter-kernelspec', args)
```

**EDIT** A better, simpler workaround here:
[Jupyter commands work only with a dash (e.g. jupyter-kernelspec instead of jupyter kernelspec)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484397/jupyter-commands-work-only-with-a-dash-e-g-jupyter-kernelspec-instead-of-jupyt)