# Jupyter commands work only with a dash (e.g. jupyter-kernelspec instead of jupyter kernelspec)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Jupyter with Anaconda3.

My `Anaconda3\` and `Anaconda3\Scripts\` folders have been added to the `%PATH%` variable.

Eventhough the `jupyter.exe` is in the `Scripts` folder above, Jupyter related commands don't work without a dash.

- For example:

  ```
  jupyter kernelspec --version
  Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelspec': [Errno 'jupyter-kernelspec' not found] 2
  ```
- The same command with a dash works:

  ```
  jupyter-kernelspec --version
  5.2.2
  ```

And the same goes for `jupyter-notebook`, etc.

Do I have to add anything else to my `%PATH%`? Am I missing something?

I have opened an issue for this point on Github as well, but it didn't get any attention unfortunately: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/381

Comment: Can you try `jupyter.exe kernelspec --version`? And see if anything changes. Also, can you add the path of both the executables to your question?

Comment: Same issue unfortunately: `Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelspec': [Errno 'jupyter-kernelspec' not found] 2`

Comment: what about the paths?

Comment: The paths are irrelevant as both locations are in my PATH environment variable.

Comment: They are actually relevant even if they are in PATH but not in same folder

Comment: In my case both are under D:/Anaconda3/Scripts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196335/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-byouness).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I figured out what's wrong. Using the `shutil` module, in some Windows versions `which('jupyter-kernelspec')` returns `None`, because of the missing `.exe`, although the `PATHEXT` environment variable contains both `.exe` and `.EXE`.

(This seems to be linked to this: [shutil.which() not finding programs without appending file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56399696/2699660) although I am not convinced because `which(jupyter-kernelespec.EXE)` using `shutil` works fine for me...)

So, one has to add the `.exe` to the argument of `jupyter` like this:

```
jupyter kernelspec.exe list
```

Because this kind of command is used by most Jupyter kernel installers, you won't always be able to go debug and check where you need to add it.
The fix consists in adding this:

```
if cmd[-4:] != '.exe':
    cmd = cmd + '.exe'
```

right before this line:
https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/blob/f1e18b8a52cd526c0cd1402b6041778dd60f20dc/jupyter_core/command.py#L102

I'll try to raise this point with `shutil` module people.

I've updated also the github issue and closed it.
https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/381

Comment: Which format do you have for your hard driver? Is it NTFS case sensitive? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998669/windows-ntfs-and-case-sensitivity

Comment: Yep, it is NTFS. But although I have both `.exe` and `.EXE` in my `PATHEXT` env variable, it doesn't work unless I add the `.exe` manually as explained in my answer above.

Comment: Looking at the source, all the extension are actually used? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/18c5f9d44dde37c0fae5585a604c6027825252d2/Lib/shutil.py#L1363

Comment: I know, no idea why it doesn't actually work: `which('jupyter-kernelspec')` returns `None` while both `which('jupyter-kernelspec.EXE')` and `which('jupyter-kernelspec.exe')` return the path. And both extensions `.exe` and `.EXE` are in my PATHEXT environment variable.
Anyway, I guess I'll close this point since I managed to work around my issue. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does your `PATHEXT` environment variable have a trailing semicolon? If so, it may be the same issue described in the similar issue you mentioned in your answer: [shutil.which() not finding programs without appending file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399696/shutil-which-not-finding-programs-without-appending-file-extension/)

Remove any trailing semicolon from `PATHEXT` and try again.

Comment: Here is my `PATHEXT`: .`COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC` it doesn't contain a trailing semicolon.